# Finding minimum, maximum and range of character count in every line of a TXT file

Tags: python, count, max, min, txt

I have a text file and I need to count the number of characters per line and then print the minimum, maximum value and range.
Example (txt file):

```
lzaNDDRipfohkALungYAipuOhbWIpkmsSqvXkjRYNxCADTUKzS
aQLi
DwhhJfvUd
```

The output should be:

- Min: 4 characters
- Max: 50 characters
- Range: 46 characters

and NULL if the file is empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the built-in [`min()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min) and [`max()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) methods, using the built-in [`len()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len) method as the keys:

```
with open("file.txt", "r") as f:
    lines = f.read().splitlines()

mi = len(min(lines, key=len))
ma = len(max(lines, key=len))
ra = ma - mi

print(f"Min: {mi} Max: {ma} Range: {ra}")
```

Output:

```
Min: 4 Max: 50 Range: 46
```

Comment: @superbrain Sorry, I don't have my IDLE currently, so I goofed.

Comment: Hmm, still easy to do at for example repl.it